# How to install version 12 of nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl, npm

I am trying to install version 12 of nodejs with command

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash
```

but still getting version 8 of nodejs and also npm is not installed

Comment: Hi SHAR MEHMOOD, welcome to StackOverflow! You need to clarify your question, where are you trying to install NodeJs 12? Linux? Mac? Windows? Which version? etc.

Comment: A word of advice - use nvm: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the complete instructions for installing node from that distribution is two commands:

```bash
# install the source list, let apt-get install 'find' the nodejs package
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | sudo -E bash -
```

```bash
# apt-get now knows about nodejs package
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

you'll find that when you follow these instructions, the script will print how to install yarn, and you should do that, also several commands (for adding sources, keys, and then installing the packages from those lists).

### Suggested method

I would suggest using the [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) library, because it doesn't require any OS modification, like so:

```
sudo npm i -g n
sudo n 20
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following link to download
https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.13.0/node-v12.13.0-x64.msi

Comment: Please explain what the relevant part of your solution is. The fact that it is a microsoft installer? The version? The special source to download from? Why is the effect of what you propose? How does that solve the problem? Try for [answer]nd consider taking the [tour] please.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).